# Adding two polynomials

Tags: c

I am trying to add two polynomial functions and store the answer into first one. So far I have this:

```
// co = coefficient, ex = exponent
void add_polynom(int co1[], int ex1[], int co2[], int ex2[])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < dataSize; j++)
        {
            if (ex1[i] == ex2[j])
            {
                co1[i] = co1[i] + co2[i];
                co2[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Explain the naming of your variables please.

Comment: co = coefficient, ex = exponent

Comment: I think there might be issues in case, say the first polynomial is `x+1` and the second one is `x^2 + 1`.

Comment: You don't need two nested loop for this. Just one loop will suffice -- the index is used for both polynomials.

Comment: can you please provide example, i am using two loops because there are 2 exponent and two coefficient.

Comment: Consider this: ∑(aᵢ xⁱ) + ∑(bᵢ xⁱ) = ∑(aᵢ + bᵢ) xⁱ. The sums are simple loops over one index, i.

Comment: (But now I see my error: you store the exponents explicitly, whereas my single loop construct uses all exponents up to the maximum. As Adit said: adding x² + 1 and x + 1 will cause trouble in your version, because you have to create space for new exponents. I suggest you skip the exponents array and just use coefficients that may be zero: {1, 0, 1} and {0, 1, 1}. Your version has other flaws. It is, for example, not clear what `dataSize` is and why it is the same for both polynomials.)

Comment: @user2962635 Best to put relevant info in the post and not just the  
comments.

Comment: @user2962635 Are the exponents _specified_ to be in the same ascending/descending order (which order is used?) and not to use a repeated exponent?

Comment: And do you use a sentinel value to end the stretch of active terms, for example a zero coefficient?

Comment: In which order are terms stored in the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your representation of polynomials is impractical:

- you iterate in 2 nested loops (quadratic complexity) to try and match the corresponding terms of both polynomials, but if the second has a power that the first does not have, it will be missing in the sum.
- you pass the degree as a global variable `dataSize` that may have an inappropriate value.

You should instead use an array of coefficients for all exponents from `0` to the degree of the polynomial and pass the destination polynomial and its degree this way:

```
/* add 2 polynomials into a destination array.
 * count variables are the sizes of the arrays,
 *   ie 1 more than the degree of the polynomials.
 * return the size of the resulting polynomial,
 *   potentially larger than the size of the destination array.
 */
int add_polynomials(int dest[], int dest_count,
                    const int co1[], int count1,
                    const int co2[], int count2) {
    /* compute the result coefficients */
    int i, count;
    for (i = count = 0; i < dest_count; i++) {
        int coef = 0;
        if (i < count1)
            coef += co1[i];
        if (i < count2)
            coef += co2[i];
        dest[i] = coef;
        if (coef != 0)
            count = i + 1;
    }
    /* determine the result count */
    for (; i < count1 && i < count2; i++) {
        if (co1[i] + co2[i] != 0)
            count = i + 1;
    }
    for (; i < count1; i++) {
        if (co1[i] != 0)
            count = i + 1;
    }
    for (; i < count2; i++) {
        if (co2[i] != 0)
            count = i + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you must use the given prototype and global definition for `dataSize`, you could use 2 nested loops indeed, but depending on how the exponents are used in both polynomials, it might be impossible to fit the result in the destination array:

- the source polynomials can each have up to `dataSize` terms with any range of exponents.  The resulting polynomial might have a total number of terms that exceeds `dataSize` and thus not representable in an array of size `dataSize`.
- your code fails because you wrote `co1[i] = co1[i] + co2[i];` instead of `co1[i] = co1[i] + co2[j];`, but you also modify `co2[i]`, which is inappropriate and you miss the terms that are only present in `co2`/`ex2`.

If we can assume that the maximum exponent is less than `dataSize`, here is an efficient approach (linear time) that will generate a result in normalized form:

```
#define dataSize  50

// co = coefficients, ex = exponents
void add_polynom(int co1[], int ex1[], int co2[], int ex2[]) {
    int res[dataSize] = { 0 };
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        res[ex1[i]] += co1[i];
        res[ex2[i]] += co2[i];
    }
    j = 0;
    for (i = dataSize; i-- > 0;) {
        if (res[i] != 0) {
            co1[j] = res[i];
            ex1[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (j < dataSize) {
        co1[j] = ex1[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely right you method is perfect but i have to use this function void add_polynom(int co1[], int ex1[], int co2[], int ex2[]) and datasize is 50.

Comment: @user2962635: it was not obvious you had to implement `void add_polynom(int co1[], int ex1[], int co2[], int ex2[])` with a global `dataSize` of `50`. Such constraints must be stated, especially given how counter intuitive they are.

Comment: @user2962635, As we explained, it's not possible. At least, not unless you can make further guarantees about the inputs you haven't made. Can you guarantee that `ex1` and `ex2` both contain 0..49 (in any order)?

Comment: add 2 polynomials and store result in first polynomial (arrays co1[] and ex1[]).

Comment: @user2962635, As we explained, it's not possible. At least, not unless you can make further guarantees about the inputs you haven't made. Can you guarantee that `ex1` contains all the value from `ex2`?

Comment: The code at the bottom assumes that no exponent is greater that `49`, but no such assumption was a made. And if such as assumption can be made, that there's an simpler solution.

Comment: @ikegami: Please! I stated the restriction: *If we can assume that the maximum exponent is less than `dataSize`*.  If we can further assume that all exponents are present in the `ex1` and `ex2` arrays, there are simpler solutions and if they are in the same order, there are indeed faster solutions, but I only assumed that the exponents are in `0..49`.

Comment: Ignore "*And if such as assumption can be made, [then] there's an simpler solution.*"

Comment: Re "*If we can further assume that all exponents are present in the ex1 and ex2 arrays*", You almost made that assumption. You assumed that there are fewer than 50 different exponents between the two polynomials.

Comment: @ikegami: The assumption I made is a much simpler.  The OP's representation calls for a simple form with just non-zero terms in descending exponent order and trailing elements with 0 coefficient and exponent, a direct translation from the common algebraic notation.

Comment: That's not true at all. Your code works perfectly fine if they are in different order. You only assumed that the highest exponent would be less than DATASIZE. With that came the free assumption that there are fewer than 50 different exponents between the two polynomials.

Comment: @ikegami: it did not assume the input polynomials were in any particular form, just that *the maximum exponent is less than `dataSize`*, as stated. More precisely, all exponents in `ex1` and `ex2` are assumed to be `>= 0` and `< dataSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example say `7x^3 + 2x + 1` as first and `5x^4 + 9x^2` as second polynomial. Now `dataSize` becomes 5(since higher degree of both is 4).

Now `co1` would be {1, 2, 0, 7, 0} and `co2` would be {0, 0, 9, 0, 5}.

```
       for (i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
       {
            co1[i] += co2[i];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is "suboptimal". It forces guarantees to to be made for it to work at all.

- Use option 1 if you can guarantee that all values of `exs1` and `exs2` are in [0..(*DATASIZE*-1)].
- Use option 2 if you can merely guarantee that there are fewer than *DATASIZE* different values in `exs1` and `exs2` combined.

**Option 1**

This solution's performance is bound by O(N).

```
#define DATASIZE 50

void panic(const char* msg) {
   fprintf(stderr, msg);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

find_ex(ex, 

// Assumes all values in exs1 are in [0..49].
// Assumes all values in exs2 are in [0..49].
void add_polynom(int cos1[], int exs1[], int cos2[], int exs2[]) {
    int cos_sum[DATASIZE];
    size_t i;
    int exs1i, exs2i;

    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; )
       cos_sum[i] = 0;

    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; ) {
        if (exs1[i] < 0 || exs1[i] >= DATASIZE || exs2[i] < 0 || exs2[i] >= DATASIZE)
            panic("add_polynom: Exponent out of range\n");

        cos_sum[exs1[i]] += cos1[i];
        cos_sum[exs2[i]] += cos2[i];
    }

    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; ) {
        cos1[i] = cos_sum[i];
        exs1[i] = i;

        cos2[i] = 0;
        /* exs2[i] = i; */
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

This solution's performance is bound by O(N<sup>2</sup>). The bound can be reduced to O(N) by using an associative array instead of `find_index_of_ex`, but that's too much work for this answer.

```
#define DATASIZE 50

void panic(const char* msg) {
   fprintf(stderr, msg);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ssize_t find_index_of_ex(int ex, int cos[], int exs[], size_t size) {
    ssize_t i;
    for (i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        if (exs[i] == ex) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

// Assumes there are fewer than DATASIZE different values in exs1 and exs2 combined.
void add_polynom(int cos1[], int exs1[], int cos2[], int exs2[]) {
    int cos_sum[];
    int exs_sum[];
    ssize_t lookup_is_by_ex[datasize];
    size_t i, sum_count;
    ssize_t i_sum;

    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; ) {
       cos_sum[i] = 0;
       exs_sum[i] = 0;
    }

    sum_count = 0;
    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; ) {
        if (cos1[i] == 0)
            continue;

        i_sum = find_index_of_ex(exs1[i], exs_sum, sum_count);
        if (i_sum >= 0)
           cos_sum[i_sum] += cos1[i];
           continue;
        }

        if (sum_count == DATASIZE)
            panic("add_polynom: Too many different exponents\n");

        cos_sum[sum_count] = cos1[i];
        exs_sum[sum_count] = exs1[i];
        ++sum_count;
    }

    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; ) {
        if (cos2[i] == 0)
            continue;

        i_sum = find_index_of_ex(exs2[i], exs_sum, sum_count);
        if (i_sum >= 0)
           cos_sum[i_sum] += cos2[i];
           continue;
        }

        if (sum_count == DATASIZE)
            panic("add_polynom: Too many different exponents\n");

        cos_sum[sum_count] = cos2[i];
        exs_sum[sum_count] = exs2[i];
        ++sum_count;
    }

    for (i=DATASIZE; i--; ) {
        cos1[i] = cos_sum[i];
        exs1[i] = exs_sum[i];

        cos2[i] = 0;
        /* exs2[i] = i; */
    }
}
```